# Lambda layer doesn't pass mask properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I encountered an issue with the Lambda layer. The inner function of the Lambda layer is supposed to take the mask tensor passed from the previous layer. I made a simple case where this does not work properly.

```
import numpy as np
import keras

def inner_fn(var, mask=None):
    print('print mask in inner_fn', mask)    
    return mask

arr_in = np.ones((2,3, 3))
arr_in[:, 0, :] = 0.
arr_out = np.ones((2,3,3))

x = keras.Input((None, 3))
mask_layer_out = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value = 0.)(x)
y = keras.layers.Lambda(inner_fn)(mask_layer_out)
model = keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
model.fit(arr_in, arr_out, epochs=1)
```

With this code, the print in the inner_fn is called twice, as follows:

```
print mask in inner_fn Tensor("masking_1/Any_1:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=bool)
print mask in inner_fn None
```

The first is what I believe is right. But I don't know why there is a second print, and for the second time, the mask is `None`. Moreover, due to mask being `None`, the model can not be compiled, raising
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`

Is this an issue of Lambda layer?
My keras version is 2.2.4, tensorflow 1.12.0, and windows 10.

Comment: `inner_fn` is being called twice. The first time, it's being called such that `var` and `mask` are both filled, while the second time it's being called such that only `var` is being filled, so `mask` becomes `None` and causes the error. Change the print statement to `print('Var: ', var, ', Mask: ', mask)` to see this.

Comment: Thanks @LukeDeLuccia If this is the case, how am I supposed to use the mask to do something in the `inner_fn`? it's not gonna to work right? since the mask is none, rather than being passed from previous.